# Java code to search database table using dates picked from two JDatePickers

Tags: java, postgresql

i am currently programming a Java application that will help users(clients) to search a table in a Postgresql database (Ver 1.18.1) by picking the start date and the end date from two Jdatepicker. The Jdatepickers i downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdatepicker/ AND http://jdatepicker.org/.

The problem is i have hit a wall in programming with Java to make the Jdatepickers to pick the dates from the database and display the information on a Jtable. I would like fellow StackOverflow programming experts to help me write a search button code that when a client selects start and end date from the Jdatepickers and clicks on the search button, the code will put into action the sql statement and retrieve the required information and display on the Jtable.

The code below shows everything as displayed on the image.

```
import org.jdatepicker.DefaultComponentFactory;
import org.jdatepicker.JDatePicker;

    public class transaction extends JInternalFrame {



    private JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();  

    private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();

    private JLabel label = new JLabel("transaction");


        private JDatePicker sdate = new DefaultComponentFactory().createJDatePicker();

        private JDatePicker edate = new DefaultComponentFactory().createJDatePicker();


    private JButton printButton;

    private JTable table;

    private TableColumn column = null;

    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

        private Connection connection;

        private JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");

        private JButton cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");


        private ResultSetTableModel tableModel;


    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "I have this already";


        public transaction() throws SQLException, ParseException{



            // the code below displays and forms the JDatePickers
                sdate.setTextEditable(true);
                edate.setTextEditable(true);
        sdate.setShowYearButtons(true);
                edate.setShowYearButtons(true);
        northPanel.add((JComponent)sdate);
                northPanel.add((JComponent)edate);
        northPanel.setVisible(true);

                northPanel.add(searchButton);

                searchButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));


            //code for search button
                searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (ae.getSource()==searchButton){
      // i need the code for the search button such that when a client selects JDatepickers sdate and edate, the sql statement and java code will be able to select the information from the database table(s) and display it on a JTable.


                    }

            }
        });

       }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're not quite getting the layering. First, write the UI to get the two dates to local variables and output them on stderr (System.out.println).  Then write code to send the SQL to fetch the desired range (or use something like Hibernate for that). Then process the results from the query. Finally, present that as a JTable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I have already designed everything but i couldn't post the image because the platform requires one to reach a certain level in order to do so. What i would like is java code that will pick the values from the JDatepickers, compare them with data in the database and output it on a JTable.